# Manually create many-to-many relations - error on setting the relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='category_products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to push some predefined data to the items:

```
 item = Item.objects.create(id=pk,name=name, categories=category.id)
```

I get the following error:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited.
```

Comment: is your model name product or item? the query is bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error should be clear, you cannot assign directly to a many-to-many field. Need to create the object, and use `add` method for adding

```
product = Product.objects.create(id=pk,name=name)
category = Category.objects.get(pk=category.id)
product.categories.add(category)
product.save()
```

If you have multiple values use `product.categories.add(*categories)`

Note that categories is list object.

Refer to documentation  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/